# RTC commands to extract files with an unique idenfier

Tags: rtc

Is there a way to extract files using RTC CLI by providing just a unique identifier (like workitem #?) and not provide the workspace UUID/name?

The following commands:

- lscm list changesets -u username -r URL:9443/ccm -W 70

*Change sets:
    (1187*

- lscm list changes -u username -r URL:9443/ccm -j 1187

*"changes": [
        {
            "author":
...
"path": "/unresolved/DeployFile1",
 ...*

- lscm get change 1187 /DeployFile1 -u username -r URL:9443/ccm /DeployFile1

*Problem running 'get change':
Unable to determine workspace. Specify workspace. Try 'lscm help get change' for more information.*

don't work as the last command is unable to determine the workspace.

We have a deployment tool that is supposed to query RTC and grab the file(s) based on user provided input (workitem # in this case). We want to keep it simple for the users and don't want to ask for workitem UUID and workspace UUID.

Any ideas? Thanks!